# magento 2 import logs

Tags: import, magento2.2, log

i'm having a problem importing additional_attributes for products. i have them formatted the way the export file looks, but when i import them, it shows import completed fine but does not update any of the custom attributes. are there any logs available for magento 2 imports? i checked out this article, [Are there any csv import logs kept?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/9048/are-there-any-csv-import-logs-kept), but it appears to be for magento 1.

Answer (score 0):

Attributes from additional column can be separated to columns on import, you can find working example file here https://github.com/firebearstudio/magento2-import-export-sample-files/blob/master/Improved%20Import%20:%20Export%20-%20Sample%20Files/products_all_types.csv

By default Magento 2 don't have import logs, only output which you get after run import on admin, our free extension add some logging to file https://github.com/firebearstudio/importexportfree